# how to use an ArrayList of FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, android, file, outputstream

I want to use ArrayList FileOutputStream to write multiple files at the same time in the internal storage of an android tablet.

```
for(int i = 0; i< fileName.size(); i++){    
    filef.get(i).renameTo(getFilesDir());
        //= File(getFilesDir(), (fileName.get(i).toString()));
    try {
        if (filef.get(i).exists()) {    
            Log.d(TAG, "les fichiers sont deja cree");
        } else {    
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName.get(i),
            Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);  
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File file = getFilesDir();
    Log.d("TAG", file.getAbsolutePath());
    appPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    // internal.setFile();
    setDefaultKeyMode(DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL);
}
```

For one file i used

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName,
            Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

and i have no problem.

Comment: `List<? extends OutputStream> lstFiles = new ArrayList<FileOutputStream>()`?

Comment: What is `filef` and what is the error?

Comment: Format your code properly!

Comment: public static List<File> filef = new ArrayList<File>();        private List<FileOutputStream>                                              fos = new ArrayList<FileOutputStream>();


i tried 

fos.get(i)= openFileOutput(fileName.get(i),

        Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE); but the problem is The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: i would like to have an output for each file

Comment: `filef.get(i).renameTo(getFilesDir());` is unlikely to work.

Comment: also, please read ArrayList documentation, and specifically search for the "add" keyword.

Comment: Yes, you might use your other approach but with using the add-function. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for the documentation of `ArrayList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need `fos.set(i, openFileOutput(fileName.get(i), Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE));`